# Knife Project with UV Sphere

Tags: mesh

I am wanting to make a depression in an object using a UV Sphere. I create the sphere and position it, then shift-select the object and enter edit mode. When I select the knife project tool, I get an error message "No other selected objects found to use for projection". Why does a UV sphere not work with this tool?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [can't use knife project](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128683/cant-use-knife-project)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't use "Knife Project"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128683/cant-use-knife-project)